# Linking PyCharm and Pip-Libaries

Tags: python, windows, numpy, pip, pycharm

I have some problems with pycharm on a Windows 10.

The problem:
I've installed python 3.7 and with it pip. After that I updated pip to the newest version. Later I installed numpy, scipy etc. using pip.
But if I start pycharm and want to import numpy, it is stated that the package is not installed. But it is installed! :D I checked it with pip list.

Do anyone has an idea? That would be awesome! :)

Bests,
Tim

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Python on your machine?

Comment: You should check which Python interpreter your PyCharm is using, maybe it's using a different one from what you expect. `ctrl + alt + s` -> project -> interpreter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings --> Project settings --> Project Interpreter and select Python 3.7 in the dropdown. 
[image]

That should select the right python version with the right site packages and Pycharm will start to recognize the libaries.

Comment: If it is not listed there, lick on the cog on the top right, "Add" and select the proper installation/virtual environment

Comment: Nooooooo! :D That was way to easy!^^ I'm sorry...!
But thanks for the quick help! :)